# Unable to access global variable

Tags: function, variables, global-variables

I defined my variable globally so I could access it later in a function. However, I get a value of 'undefined' from within the function. Why isn't the value making it in?

Notes:
- Global variable is "combineDashes" which is an array.
- Function I want to use it in is "click
1. I tried passing the variable in as an argument to the function. Didn't work.
2. I confirmed the variable is defined and contains the correct value within the function in which it was defined.
3. I confirmed another global variable is making it into the function just fine.

Here's where combineDashes gets defined as a global variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      // upon page load

        var badGuesses;   // reset bad guess counter
        var theWord;        // defines variable globally
        var combineDashes;   // defines variable globally
        var letter;     // defines variable globally
        var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];   // array of letters to choose
        $("#lettersRemaining").html(alphabet);  // gets elements of the alphabet array and displays on UI
```

Here's the function where combineDashes gets defined (as an array):

```
//  N E W  G A M E  B U T T O N   C L I C K E D

    $("#newGame").click(function() {    // when user clicks on Start New Game button...

        $("#status").hide();   // upon game reset hide the status section stating game over
        var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];   // reset array of letters to choose from

        $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-0.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman no limbs" width="144" height="216">'); // reset hangman image
        badGuesses = 0;   // reset guess counter which is used later

        var wordCollection = ["MANSION", "STATUE", "GORILLA", "NOTEBOOK", "SMARTPHONE", "ILLUSTRATION", "PHOTO", "ELEGANT", "ARBORIST", "KEYBOARD", "CALENDAR", "CAPITAL", "TEXTBOOK", "HORRIBLE", "LIBRARY"];  //  array of words the computer will randomly choose from

        theWord = wordCollection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordCollection.length)]; // randomly selects a word
            console.log("theWord is ....");
            console.log(theWord);

        var theWordLength = theWord.length;     // Get number of characters in randomly selected word to know how many dashes to display
            console.log("theWordLength is ....");
            console.log(theWordLength);

        // D I S P L A Y  D A S H E S

        var combineDashes = []; // creates an array to hold the number of dashes inside the for loop

        for (var i = theWordLength; i > 0; i--) 
            {
                combineDashes.push(" - ");  // each loop through adds a dash to the array
            }

        combineDashes.join(" ");  // joins cumulative dashes and converts to a string

        $("#dashes").html(combineDashes); // displays dashes on UI
                console.log("combineDashes is...");
                console.log(combineDashes);

    });
```

Here's where I try to access the combineDashes variable:

```
    //  F O R  B A D  G U E S S E S
        if (indices.length === 0)   //  if bad guess 
            {
                badGuesses++;    // increment bad guess counter
                $("#status").show();
                $("#status").html("Sorry, " + letter + " is incorrect. Try again.");  // status message displays
                console.log("Total badGuesses...");
                console.log(badGuesses); 

                //  remove guessed letter from alphabet
                var alphaIndex = alphabet.indexOf(letter);      // gets index of letter in alphabet
                alphabet.splice(alphaIndex,1);  // removes the letter from the alphabet array
                console.log("alphabet index of letter guessed...");
                console.log(alphaIndex);
                $("#lettersRemaining").html(alphabet);  // refreshes letters remaining

            // display correct hangman image based on how many bad guesses
                    if (badGuesses === 1) 
                    {
                        $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-1.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 1 limb" width="144" height="216">');
                    }
                    else if (badGuesses === 2)
                    {
                            $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-2.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 2 limbs" width="144" height="216">');
                    }
                    else if (badGuesses === 3)
                    {
                            $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-3.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 3 limbs" width="144" height="216">');
                    }
                    else if (badGuesses === 4)
                    {
                            $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-4.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 4 limbs" width="144" height="216">');
                    }
                    else if (badGuesses === 5)
                    {
                            $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-5.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 5 limbs" width="144" height="216">');
                    }
                    else if (badGuesses === 6)
                    {
                            $("#hangmanGuy").html('<img src="img/Hangman-6.png" id="hangmanImg" alt="pic of hangman 6 limbs" width="144" height="216">');
                            $("#status").html("Game Over. Sorry, you lose. Click Start New Game and try again.");  // status message displays
                    }
            }
        //  F O R  G O O D  G U E S S E S
        else
            {
                //  remove guessed letter from alphabet
                var alphaIndex = alphabet.indexOf(letter);      // gets index of letter in alphabet

                alphabet.splice(alphaIndex,1);  // removes the letter from the alphabet array
                    console.log("alphabet index of letter guessed...");
                    console.log(alphaIndex);

                $("#lettersRemaining").html(alphabet);  // refreshes letters remaining

            // replace dash(es) with letter

                combineDashes[indices] = letter;       // <---  HUNG UP HERE !!!!   
                console.log(letter);
                console.log(combineDashes);


                $("#status").show();
                $("#status").html(letter + " is correct! Go again.");  // status message displays


            }


    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var combineDashes = [] should be  combineDashes = [] or else you are setting a new local variable where you wanted to set the global.

Comment: @dropye I did not see your answer while I was typing (17 second difference), but I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Iam not really sure but I think you should delete the 'var' from the following line

```
var combineDashes = []; // creates an array to hold the number of dashes inside the for loop
```

I guess the script creates a new local variable with this name wich is thrown away after the function ends

Comment: Works!!   However, I see that when the indices array contains more than one index (Hangman game and the letter guessed is contained more than once in the word) the dashes don't update correctly.  Should I open a new question for this?  Works fine if the letter is found only once int he word.

Comment: I think you have to open a new question, since in the current one we do not see where indices is declared or set.